# Timeout within session while sending requests

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, python-requests, timeout

I'm trying to learn how I can use `timeout` within a session while sending requests. The way I've tried below can fetch the content of a webpage but I'm not sure this is the right way as I could not find the usage of `timeout` in this [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/user/advanced/).

```
import requests

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link,timeout=5)
    print(r.text)
```

How can I use timeout within session?

Comment: According to the doc, (link,timeout=5) is the correct way to use timeout. Do you have any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure this is the right way as I could not find the usage of `timeout` in this [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/user/advanced/).

Scroll to the bottom. It's definitely there. You can search for it in the page by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and entering `timeout`.

You're using `timeout` correctly in your code example.

You can actually specify the timeout in a few different ways, as explained in the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts):

> If you specify a single value for the timeout, like this:
>
> `r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=5)`
>
> The timeout value will be applied to both the `connect` and the `read` timeouts. Specify a tuple if you would like to set the values separately:
>
> `r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=(3.05, 27))`
>
> If the remote server is very slow, you can tell Requests to wait forever for a response, by passing None as a timeout value and then retrieving a cup of coffee.
>
> `r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=None)`

Try using [`https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000`](https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000) to test your code.

For example, this raises an exception because 0.2 seconds is not long enough to establish a connection with the server:

```py
import requests

link = "https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000"

with requests.Session() as s:
    try:
        r = s.get(link, timeout=(0.2, 10))
        print(r.text)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpstat.us', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.2)
```

This raises an exception because the server waits for 5 seconds before sending the response, which is longer than the 2 second `read` timeout set:

```py
import requests

link = "https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000"

with requests.Session() as s:
    try:
        r = s.get(link, timeout=(3.05, 2))
        print(r.text)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpstat.us', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)
```

You specifically mention using a timeout within a session. So maybe you want a session object which has a default timeout. Something like this:

```py
import requests

link = "https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000"

class EnhancedSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, timeout=(3.05, 4)):
        self.timeout = timeout
        return super().__init__()

    def request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        print("EnhancedSession request")
        if "timeout" not in kwargs:
            kwargs["timeout"] = self.timeout
        return super().request(method, url, **kwargs)

session = EnhancedSession()

try:
    response = session.get(link)
    print(response)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    print(e)

try:
    response = session.get(link, timeout=1)
    print(response)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    print(e)

try:
    response = session.get(link, timeout=10)
    print(response)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
EnhancedSession request
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpstat.us', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=4)
EnhancedSession request
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpstat.us', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)
EnhancedSession request
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 22):

According to the [Documentation - Quick Start](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/?highlight=timeout#timeouts).

> You can tell Requests to stop waiting for a response after a given
> number of seconds with the timeout parameter. Nearly all production code should use this parameter in nearly all requests.
>
> ```
> requests.get('https://github.com/', timeout=0.001)
> ```

Or from the [Documentation Advanced Usage](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=timeout#timeouts) you can set 2 values (***connect*** and ***read*** timeout)

> The timeout value will be applied to both the ***connect*** and the ***read***
> timeouts. Specify a tuple if you would like to set the values
> separately:
>
> ```
> r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=(3.05, 27))
> ```

#### Making Session Wide Timeout

Searched throughout the documentation and it seams it is not possible to set ***timeout*** parameter session wide.

But there is a [GitHub Issue Opened](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3070) (*Consider making Timeout option required or have a default*) which [provides a workaround](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3070#issuecomment-205070203) as an `HTTPAdapter` you can use like this:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

class TimeoutHTTPAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "timeout" in kwargs:
            self.timeout = kwargs["timeout"]
            del kwargs["timeout"]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        timeout = kwargs.get("timeout")
        if timeout is None and hasattr(self, 'timeout'):
            kwargs["timeout"] = self.timeout
        return super().send(request, **kwargs)
```

And mount on a `requests.Session()`

```
s = requests.Session() 
s.mount('http://', TimeoutHTTPAdapter(timeout=5)) # 5 seconds
s.mount('https://', TimeoutHTTPAdapter(timeout=5))
...
r = s.get(link) 
print(r.text)
```

or similarly you can use the proposed  [`EnhancedSession`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62044757/1207193) by @GordonAitchJay

```
with EnhancedSession(5) as s: # 5 seconds
    r = s.get(link)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: In the snippets above, I believe it should be `s.mount('http://', TimeoutHTTPAdapter(timeout=5))` and `s.mount('https://', TimeoutHTTPAdapter(timeout=5))`.